# multi-way merge vs 2-way merge

Tags: algorithm, mergesort, external-sorting

When we [externally merge sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/External_sorting) a large file, we split it into small ones, sort those, and then merge them back into a large sorted file.

When merging, we can either do many 2-way merge passes, or one multi-way merge.

I am wondering which approach is better? and why?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One multi-way merge is generally better.  Consider three small files:

```
a1
a2
a3
```

and

```
b1
b2
b3
```

and finally

```
c1
c2
c3
```

If you do a merge with `a` and `b`, we're left with (say)

```
a1
b1
a2
b2
b3
a3
```

and

```
c1
c2
c3
```

A final merge would create the sorted list, but notice how in this final merge we have to visit the `a` and `b` items again.  It's this re-merging that is wasteful in cascading two-way merges.

What you can do instead is a single multi-way merge.  However, be careful how you do it.  Specifically, avoid the naive double-loop that scans each cursor to see which has the minimum value.  Use a min-heap instead.  This will bring the complexity back down to `O(n log n)`.